# Growth of percentage of numbers with the digit 4 in it as number of digits increase

Tags: probability

My parents are superstitious, and do not want me to buy a home with the number 4 in the address.  I think this is absurd, since this will eliminate 10% of the units on the market if addresses only have 1 digit (there is one 4 in the range of 0-9), 19% of the units on the market if there are 2 digits in the address (there are 19 numbers with 4s between 0-99, inclusive), 27.1% if addresses have 3 digits.  For each of these scenarios, I am assuming that the addresses extend from 0 to the max value for the number of digits.

I made a simple script to understand the growth of this percentage as the number of digits increase.

```
def num4(num_digits):
    count=0
    max_digit=int('9'*num_digits)
    print(f"{num_digits=}", f"{max_digit=}")
    for i in range(max_digit+1):
        try:
            str(i).index('4')
            count+=1
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return count

for i in range(1,15):
    count=num4(i)
    print("\t", "count", count, "percentage:", count/(int('9'*i)+1))
```

Here are some of the output for this script.

```
num_digits=1 max_digit=9
     count 1 percentage: 0.1
num_digits=2 max_digit=99
     count 19 percentage: 0.19
num_digits=3 max_digit=999
     count 271 percentage: 0.271
num_digits=4 max_digit=9999
     count 3439 percentage: 0.3439
num_digits=5 max_digit=99999
     count 40951 percentage: 0.40951
num_digits=6 max_digit=999999
     count 468559 percentage: 0.468559
num_digits=7 max_digit=9999999
     count 5217031 percentage: 0.5217031
```

My script is slow.  Since it is not uncommon for addresses to have 14 digits in it (3 for street number, 2 for room number, 9 for zip), I want to know if there is an upper limit for the percentage of homes that I must reject as the number of digits in a home address increases.  Clearly this number will never get to 100%, regardless of the number of digits, since there will always be some numbers without a 4 in it.

Comment: There are $8\cdot 9^{n-1}$ $n-$digit numbers without a $4.$ This means the percentage is $$\frac{9\cdot 10^{n-1}-8\cdot 9^{n-1}}{9\cdot 10^{n-1}}=1-\frac89\cdot\left(\frac9{10}\right)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of $n$-digit strings not containing a $4$ (or indeed any fixed digit) is $9^n$, so the proportion of those strings that *do* contain a $4$ is simply $1-0.9^n$. For $n=14$ this evaluates to $77.1\%$ – and this number gets arbitrarily close to $1$ as $n\to\infty$, meaning that your parents are indeed absurd.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that thinking further.

Comment: Thanks. $1-0.9^n$ is much more elegant.